# InstantRails Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instant

When I try to run InstantRails 2.0 under Vista, which I've extracted to C:\InstantRails, I get the following error:

Either Apache or MySQL cannot run because another program is using its port.

What do I do here?  MySQL server is installed fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InstantRails will tell you in its console exactly which one can't run with its traffic lights. It's most likely a clash between Apache and Vista's built in web server (IIS) on port 80. I'd go open up the Services list and turn IIS (may be called 'HTTP Web server' or something similar) off.

And, to be honest, as useful as InstantRails was, it's not actively maintained. Bitnami's RubyStack is a fair substitute although it's larger, takes longer to install, and doesn't have the nice pointy-clicky interface for starting mongrel instances that InstantRails (RIP) did.

Comment: We are working on the pointy-clicky stuff :)  OS X version already has nice GUI tool for that. http://bitami.org/stack/rubystack